# MobileFirst Android Native App

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have trouble deploying MFP native app onto my device. I am able to run the app on my emulator without any issue. Did I miss any library? I am using MFP 7.1 SDK in Native Android application.

I receive the following error.

> Target device: samsung-sm_g9117d-83251514e46 
>   Installing APK:/Users/UserName/Documents/workspace3/MFPApp/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
>   Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.project.mfp.mfpapp Installing
>   com.project.mfp.mfpapp DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r
>   "/data/local/tmp/com.project.mfp.mfpapp"
>   pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.project.mfp.mfpapp 
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you face [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS] error means that you are trying to install an app that was compiled for a archicteure that is different of your device.

If you compiled an app for armv and install it on an device that uses Intel architecture, it will fail.

**HOW TO COMPILE FOR DIFFERENT ARCHITECTURES?**

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100291/how-to-target-different-android-architectures)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268647/gradle-android-build-for-different-processor-architectures)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420312/how-to-target-multiple-architectures-using-ndk)

[Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682462/android-studio-how-to-run-a-single-test-on-x86)

Comment: How do I switch between architecture in Android Studio? I have added both the ARM and x86 MobileFirst libraries.

Comment: This is another question. You should mark the reply as correct. But I will help you.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to install an app that has native libraries in it, but doesn't have a library for your mobile's cpu architecture.
Check if these threads would help

[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS how to overcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751350/install-failed-no-matching-abis-how-to-overcome)

[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when install apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572052/install-failed-no-matching-abis-when-install-apk)